# Joining Multiple DEs - system error

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql

We're having problems joining multiple DEs to bring back every row of data. We're using this SQL:

```
FROM CIPD_Master_Contact_DE MC

FULL JOIN Contact_Salesforce_2 SF ON MC.Contact_Number=SF.CTC_Contact_Number__c 

FULL JOIN CIPD_Master_Branch_Events BE ON MC.Contact_Number=BE.Contact_Number

FULL JOIN CIPD_Master_Legacy_Enquiries LE ON MC.Contact_Number=LE.Contact_No_Int

FULL JOIN CIPD_Master_Legacy_Enquiries_Eptica LEP ON MC.Contact_Number=LEP.Contact_No_Int

FULL JOIN CIPD_Master_Exhibition_Pre_Reg_History EPR ON MC.Contact_Number=EPR.Contact_Number

FULL JOIN CIPD_Master_HR_Inform_Webinar HRI ON MC.Contact_Number=HRI.Contact_Number

FULL JOIN CIPD_Master_Renewals MR ON MC.Contact_Number=MR.Contact_Number

FULL JOIN CIPD_Master_Licence_Purchase MLP ON MC.Contact_Number=MLP.Contact_Number

FULL JOIN CIPD_Master_All_Bookings AB ON MC.Contact_Number=AB.Contact_Number




WHERE 
CTC_Membership_status__c='Active Membership'
OR
BE.Contact_Number is not NULL
OR
LE.Contact_No_Int is not NULL
OR
LEP.Contact_No_Int is not NULL
OR
EPR.Contact_Number is not NULL
OR
HRI.Contact_Number is not NULL
OR
MR.Contact_Number is not NULL
OR
MLP.Contact_Number is not NULL
OR
AB.Contact_Number is not NULL
```

And the resultant DE should probably be about 5M rows of data, total number of fields is about 300, however we get a system error every time we run it. Any help much appreciated!

Chris

Comment: Can you be more specific about the error you're getting?  Are you running the Query in an Automation?  What does it say when you hover over the failed Query step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically if [Query Activities](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/) fail, it's one of these 4 things:

1. **Primary key violation** -- your query results in duplicate rows not allowed by the primary key
2. **Inserting a null value into a non-nullable field**
3. **Inserting a value too long** for the field (truncation)
4. **Timeout** -- if your query doesn't complete within the 30 minute timeout window, it'll error out.

SFMC Support can tell you what the error is from the server log.